# Redirect all DNS-Requests with dnsmasq

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dnsmasq, adhoc-network

I have following scenario: I have set up an ad-hoc network with wicd on my server, and use dnsmasq as an dhcp- and dns-server. The network works very well, I can connect, get an ip address, and on all clients the nameserver is set to the IP of my server.
But I want that **all dns request** of the clients are resolved to my local server which runs an apache webserver. Is this possible with dnsmasq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

I use it this way:

```
/usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq -z -k -2 -i vlan9 -a 10.6.66.1 \
--address=/\#/10.6.66.1
```

`10.6.66.1` is the IP address it returns.

**UPDATE** Yes, `#` is a wildcard. You can specify multiple with `--address`

Comment: one question: the \# in the address part is the wildcard for all domainrequest, or?

Comment: thanks got it to work, but it should only be # instead of \#

Comment: It depends on your shell. It is an escape mechanism as the shell would interpret it as a comment.

Comment: ah ok you're right :D i use it in the dnsmasq.conf, therefore i haven't to escape it ;)

Answer (score 5):

The primary options to use in the conf file for this would be:

```
address=/#/10.6.66.1
interface=vlan9
```